# Meanings of values of approved_flag values in oracle payables (PO_RELEASES_ALL)

Tags: oracle, po

I want to know the meanings of values of approved_flag values in oracle payables (PO_RELEASES_ALL table). I've searched on internet for that question but sadly, no results

Could anyone who know about it tell me or suggest me a reference?

These are all values of approved_flag which are in my database.

```
1. null
2. R
3. Y
4. N
5. F
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: What exactly your question is and what have u tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited my question. I'm trying to understand the meanings of values but I can't find any document related to it.

Comment: you can search it on internet.. I am sure u will find links regarding that... We can not help in this kind of question in which someone ask for explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember:

```
Approved - Y
Requires Reapproval - R
Rejected - F
In-Process - NULL or N
```